# Продукты бр — что это?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Было испробовано последнее средство: продукты бр. Глик - розовая жидкость с запахом отравленного персика под названием "Клопин". Но и это не помогло. Положение ухудшалось. Через два года от начала великой борьбы отшельник случайно заметил, что совершенно перестал думать о смысле жизни, потому что круглые сутки занимался травлей клопов" [Илья Ильф и Евгений Петров, "Двенадцать стульев"].

Это сокращение от чего-то или падежная форма какого-то слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости, "**братьев** Глик". Другой пример использования сокращения: фабрика бр(атьев) Маркс.
https://oldsaratov.ru/tags/gubernia/zavod-volgodizelapparat-kommunist-vozrozhdenie-fabrika-br-shefer

И на известных комиков *братьев Маркс* иногда так же ссылаются:
https://the-slider04.livejournal.com/194700.html

Comment: А зачем использовано сокращение? И почему "продукты", а не "продукт"?

Comment: Во мн. числе (так или "из продуктов...") + сокращение могло быть буквально написано на этикетке (напр. на молоке "Простоквашино" пишут "ОТБОРНЫЕ ФЕРМЫ ЛЕН. ОБЛАСТИ, что бы это ни значило). Проверить это по оригиналу надписи сложно, ибо конкретно эти производители прочно забыты (хотя сейчас есть множество предприимчивых однофамильцев).

Answer (score 1):

Очень вероятно, что имеются ввиду некие братья Глик. То есть, "продукты братьев Глик".